# Rails: How to draw charts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphics, charts

I'm an amateur web developer and I would like to know how to create graphical charts and graphs from scratch.

What are some good tutorials and/or guides for producing them in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: [StackOverflow is not a link farm or search engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128549/172661). Questions about where to find tutorials or guides or anything else belong at Google (or any other favorite search site). SO is for specific questions about programming. Keeping things on-topic here keeps noise and clutter down and helps keep this a useful resource for programming questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably be better off producing them in javascript. There are lots of great libraries out there; perhaps start with [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/).

If you need more control or more exotic charts, try [d3](http://d3js.org).